# Joystick controls mixed with rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with the Fixed joystick when I apply rotation to the main camera. The controls are mixed. How can I resolve this problem? Do I need to use other type of joystick? Where I should put "-"  ?  in front of which number

```css
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Look")]
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{

    public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
    public float sensitivityX = 15F;
    public float sensitivityY = 15F;

    public float minimumX = -360F;
    public float maximumX = 360F;

    public float minimumY = -60F;
    public float maximumY = 60F;

    float rotationY = 0F;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            float turnAngleChange = (touch.deltaPosition.x / Screen.width) * sensitivityX;
            float pitchAngleChange = (touch.deltaPosition.y / Screen.height) * sensitivityY;

            // Handle any pitch rotation
            if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY || axes == RotationAxes.MouseY)
            {
                rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY + pitchAngleChange, minimumY, maximumY);
                transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0f);
            }

            // Handle any turn rotation
            if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY || axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
            {
                transform.Rotate(0f, turnAngleChange, 0f);
            }
        }

        void Start()
        {
            //if(!networkView.isMine)
            //enabled = false;

            // Make the rigid body not change rotation
            //if (rigidbody)
            //rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question so I'm gonna answer both of my interpretations.

If the rotation of the camera is inverted (if you put your stick to the left the camera rotates to the right) you just need to add a minus in front of the speed you're rotating the camera with.

If the rotation of the camera happens when you use the left stick and you want to use the right stick. Then you should define in your input a field called something like camera-rotation-x and use the axis shown on the following pictures in the article here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150323/unity3d-how-to-use-controller-joystick-to-look-around If you follow that article, your camera rotation should work.

Comment: there is a way to post a video?

Comment: You can add a link in the comments if you want to.

Comment: You've put rotationY in the x part of a Vector3. Shouldn't you put that on the y value and use the localEulerAngles.x on the x part of the Vector3?

Comment: I don't understand what you said to change, this:  new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0f); ??

Comment: Yes change `new Vector3(-rotationY, localEulerAngles.y, 0f);` to `new Vector(localEulerAngles.x, -rotationY, 0f);` it might fix it.

Comment: transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector(localEulerAngles.x, -rotationY, 0f); -------it gives me error

Comment: Oh my bad it's `transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector(transform.localEulerAngles.x, -rotationY, 0f);` I forgot that localEulerAngles is part of the transform.

Comment: `transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, -rotationY, 0f);` excuse me (again lol)

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't help you, I'm sorry.